# How to count by programmatic way the quantity of child XML nodes within parent XML node using C# and WPF?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I write a WPF application which is two-level master-details and uses XML file as data source. Below I show the content of this XML file. This file is put in Data folder that is included in project and file itself is included in project too. The name of this file is Books.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books xmlns="">
  <Category name="Computer Programming">
    <Book>
      <Author>H. Schildt</Author>
      <Title>C# 4.0 The Complete Reference</Title>
    </Book>
  </Category>
  <Category name="Art Editions">
    <Book>
      <Author>M. Cervantes</Author>
      <Title>The Ingenious Gentleman Don Quixote of La Mancha </Title>
    </Book>
    <Book>
      <Author>P. Ronsard</Author>
      <Title>Les Amours</Title>
    </Book>
  </Category>
</Books>
```

I'm in need of counting of quantity of Book nodes **within each Category node** and storing the results. How can I do it?

Comment: Why dont you use xmldocument to load the items to your view model and then simpley count the element you have? its much easier than doing it in xaml... you could also deserialize your xml to a list<Book> and then simpley use list.Count.

Comment: Thanks, Amit. But my application is not MVVM and so that I have no viewmodel in it. I'm quite newbie in XML and I don't know how can I deserialize it in List<Book> instance.

Comment: Guys, help me! I'm lost, seriously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ-to-XML's [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to achieve that, for example :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("put_path_to_xml_file_here.xml");
//loop through all <Category>
foreach (var category in doc.Root.Elements("Category"))
{
    //count <Book> elements within current <Category> element
    var numberOfBooks = category.Elements("Book").Count();
    //print the category name and the number of book elements
    Console.WriteLine((string)category.Attribute("name") + " : " + numberOfBooks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, har07. You helped me.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you can leverage your knowledge on LINQ-to-XML starting from this basic example.